# URLs that 302 Redirect to the Play Store with "market://details" do NOT show in the network tab in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-play, puppeteer

We are using Chrome Puppeteer to verify that links are redirecting to the play store properly. However, we are seeing weird behavior on both Puppeteer and Chrome Desktop where links that 302 redirect to the play store do not show in the network tab--at all (well, for Puppeteer, it just gets stuck on the previous URL). As if the requests are never made.

To reproduce, you'll need a URL whose server responds with a 302 to a market link, such as `market://details?id=com.kabam.marvelbattle`. The network tab shows no activity when visiting this URL. Is this intentional? Is there a flag that can be used to show ALL network requests, no matter the response?

EDIT: 
Example URL: `http://appclk.me/store.php`. With network tab open, visit this URL. You will see nothing happens, nothing shows in the network tab. Firefox DOES show this request.

Comment: I can get this to sometimes work and sometimes not, e.g. from the new tab page I don't see anything, but from about:blank I do. Can you include more context?

Comment: I added an example URL. It never works, even from the `about:blank` page. What I'm ACTUALLY trying to do is make sure some advertiser's links are redirecting to the play store. So the network tab will show a couple of redirects that use javascript (200 response codes), but the page with the 200 response will be the last request listed -- the pages further down the tree that 302 redirect to the store (such as my example link) never show up.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't figure out how to show all the requests in Chrome, but because my specific use case was Puppeteer, I'll post how it was solved with that:

Use the `page.setRequestInterception(true)` method to get all requests to fire in the `request` event. Then listen for the request event like so:

```
        // Set a listener for new requests
        page.on('request', request => {
            console.log(request.url);
            request.continue();
        });
```

The 302s and market link request events are fired.